# Faking instance variable in RSpec and Capybara feature spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

I'm trying to set up some feature specs before I get into refactoring some of my company's old code. It's kind of an unconventional setup, but I was able to figure out enough about test doubles to bypass the authentication enough to get started. One problem I'm still having is that some of the instance variables set in these methods I'm bypassing are expected by the view, so I get `undefined method for nil:NilClass` errors. I would like to get the specs running before I make any changes to the program code. In this case, I could easily just move the particular instance variable to another method. But I'm sure more situations like this will come up. Here's the example I'm currently working on:

```
def security_level
  @right_now = Time.now

  #
  # other code that wont work without
  # connecting to a remote authentication
  # server
  #

end
```

Then in my spec:

```
feature 'Navigation' do
  before(:each) do
    allow_any_instance_of(ApplicationController).to receive(:security_level).and_return(nil)
  end
  scenario 'is possible' do
    visit root_path
    expect(page.has_content?('Quick Stats'))
  end
end
```

Here's the error, coming from `@right_now.year` in the view

```
 Failure/Error: visit root_path
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `year' for nil:NilClass
 # ./common/views/layouts/bootstrap/layout.haml:63
```

**EDIT:** Is there a way to set instance variables on the controller from within a feature spec?

Comment: The `let` keyword/method.

Comment: In addition to using the let keyword I think you want to actually return a time rather than nil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no easy way to accomplish what you want.

The `feature` spec is handled mostly by Capybara, not RSpec. Capybara runs the majority of the browser / rails server behavior in an external process. This make it inaccessible from RSpec's point-of-view. Thus you cannot use stubs / doubles in this manner.

Feature specs are largely meant to be end-to-end acceptance tests. The idea is to exercise your system as those who would use your system do. Generally, in these types of specs you perform various "workflows". This means, having the spec, log a user in, navigate to particular pages, filling forms, clicking buttons and links. You then generally make your expectations on what you see in the view.

This means your spec would look more like:

```
feature 'Navigation' do
  let(:regular_user) { User.create!(name: 'A Regular User') }

  def sign_in(a_user)
    visit sign_in_url
    # fill out form
    click_button 'Sign In'
  end

  before(:each) do
    sign_in(regular_user)
  end

  scenario 'is possible' do
    visit root_path
    expect(page.has_content?('Quick Stats'))
  end
end
```

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. It uses some legacy code shared across several applications to connect with an LDAP server. I was able to set up a separate project that could do the full login process as you suggested here, but it required saving my own LDAP credentials in a file. Back to unit tests for now.

Comment: Without knowing more about the code it is hard to give suggestions. Even with legacy code, if this part is relatively isolated, it could be possible to shim a fake service in. You may need to do that in the test environment configuration or initializer.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/per-garden/fakeldap  may provide enough ldap functionality for your feature tests.